# Tab navigation issue in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

We are using *ag-grid* in one of our application. Tabbing into *ag-grid* form outside element is not working.

Comment: Please provide some context: code, logs, error messages, etc.

Comment: When in doubt, check [the documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#tabbing-into-the-grid) first.

Comment: @ChrisW. Thank you for your suggestion. The example which is there in document helped me to solve this problem.